# EC2 instance on a public subnet - SSH port

Tags: security, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

I have a EC2 instance that is a public subnet. 
At the same  subnet I have an EC2 Bastion instance.
In the security group, I need that the 80 port acessible to outside world, because it is running an app. service. To connect to the ssh port (22) I also put a rule in the security group, just allowing the IP from bastion server.

Is it a good practice? 
If not, how can security my instance on  public subnet?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Usually, the main purpose of a Bastion instance is to allow you to easily connect with instances in a private subnet.

So  connecting to your instance in the public subnet directly would generally be considered perfectly ok. If you want to maximize security, make sure that your security groups only allow a single IP address or your network range to connect to it from the internet and not 0.0.0.0/0. This can be a pain in the neck if you have lots of servers, and if you want to connect to it from different places, it might be hard to manage.

With the combination of a key pair authentication file (.pem) and locked down security groups, the security will be pretty tight.